How to implement Pauli Twirling error mitigation technique in qiskit?
I am studying the error mitigation techniques. There is one technique of error mitigation called as pauli twirling. I need some toy code of qiskit which can show its benefit.
It would be great if I can be helped in this.

Pauli twirling is one of error mitigation techniques supported by Qiskit runtime. You can use it with Qiskit primitives as follows:
estimator = Estimator(mode=backend)
estimator.options.twirling.enable_gates = True

See here for more details.

Thank you for the response @Egretta.Thula. I am not still able to find any basic toy kind of code using Pauli Twirling showing its advantage. Also, I want to use the counts. Please provide me some link or toy code.
